# DustJS - variable in template

Tags: dust.js

I have function which create random number.

```
dust.helpers.randomNumber = function(chunk, ctx, bodies, params) {
    return chunk.write(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
};
```

And in template I will call:

```
{@randomNumber/}
```

It works, but I want to assign return of this function to variable into tempalte. I need to user te same random number in 2-4 places.

**I found solution.** I extend my fucntion:

```
dust.helpers.randomNumber = function(chunk, ctx, bodies, params) {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        if(params !== null && params.assignToProp){
            ctx.stack.head[params.assignToProp] = number;
            return chunk.write("");
        }else
            return chunk.write(number);
};
```

And in template call:

```
{@randomNumber assignToProp="_idSuffix"/}
```

And this variable is under:

```
{._idSuffix}
```

Comment: You can `return chunk;` instead of `return chunk.write("");` `chunk.write()` returns that same `chunk` object with the string appended.

Comment: You can answer your own question, btw